# Sql query to match string after a hyphen (-)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to fetch all the records using a SQL query with the string 'John' in it. Condition is, John should appear after at least one hyphen (-)

Examples:

1. Anna - Pam - John (Yes)
2. John - Anna - Pam (No)
3. Anna - John (Yes)
4. John (No)
5. Anna - Pam - Mike - PhilJohn (Yes)
6. John - John (Yes)

Bad query example: Select * from users where name LIKE '%John%';

Comment: Have you tried `Select * from users where name LIKE '%- John%';` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use '%' in between - and John to allow any numbers of characters in between.

your query will be like this

`Select * from users where name LIKE '%-%John%';`